# Catalog price rules after 1 day only shown in the list view

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

We currently take a discount promotion.
we have created a list price rule.
`30%` discount on all products of a brand.
This is the second action in a row.
Now the following error occurs.

The new prices are displayed normally. At irregular intervals, the prices will be displayed only in the product list view.
Then the prices are not visible in the product details and shopping cart.

I then turn the catalog price rule manually. Then prices will again be displayed correctly.

In the first action, the error did not occur.
What could I do. It often came customers could receive the error `no promotional rates`.

Best Regards

Comment: Please show your code otherwise people wont be able to help find the error.

Comment: you can get error in error log file in magento

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?